# Paperclip Styles, Is there a way to pass one of the resized styles to Paperclip as an override?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

my apps allows users to FB connect, After FB connecting we grab their photo. Paperclip then resizes the large fb photo to create a thumbnail.

Example Photo: https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/41541_105_3932900_n.jpg

See the problem with this photo is the height. If I need a thumbnail and paperclip generates the thumb:

has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles => { :thumb => "100x100>" },

I now have a squished thumbnail which users hate. Though FB does provide a optimized thumbnail at 35x35. Can I pass that to paperclip to override the automatic generated paperclip thumbnail?

Essentially passing original and thumbnail. But if thumbnail isn't provided, then let paperclip generate the thumb?

Ideas?